# Deserialize binary Thrift message in Scala

Tags: scala, binary, thrift, scrooge

I am trying to desrialize a binary message in Scala:

```
val deserializer = new TDeserializer(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
    try {
      val obj = deserializer.deserialize(new ClientError{}, input._2.toArray)
```

Where ClientError is the trait generated with Scrooge from a Thrift file. The problem is, that deserialize() expects a TBase object, but TBase is an interface. How do I do this? Do I have to create a new class which implements both?
Thx for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]): ClientError = {
  val protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory
  val buffer = new TMemoryInputTransport(bytes)
  val proto = protocolFactory.getProtocol(buffer)
  ClientError.decode(proto)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't test that yet, I am having trouble generating test data b/c I can't serialize either (same reason). Can you briefly explain to me the difference between the 2 approaches and the context between Serializer, TBase and the classes/traits generated with scrooge?

Answer (score -1):

```
def getClientError(binaryData: Array[Byte]) : ClientError = {
         val tdser = new TDeserializer();  
         val cliErr = new ClientError()
         tdser.deserialize(cliErr, binaryData)
         return cliErr 
}
```